# How group of notification is handle in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

In my app when the user press a single notifications, it open the main activity and it's handle in onNewIntent method. However, as documentation say : *Note: If your app sends four or more notifications and does not specify a group, the system automatically groups them together on Android 7.0 and higher.*

When the user click on the cluster of Notification, it only open the app and doesn't call onNewIntent, i would like to handle this event. Is it possible ? How can i archive this. It's seem that the activity is recreated, the onPause and onCreate are called. This is how a create my notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, INFO_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentText(information.getContent(getApplicationContext()))
            .setContentTitle(titleId.map(integer -> getApplicationContext().getString(integer)).orElseGet(() -> _defaultTitle))
            .setSmallIcon(information.getIconId())
            .setAutoCancel(information.getAutoCancel())
            .setOngoing(information.getOngoing())
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setPriority(notificationPriority)
            .setShowWhen(information.getShowWhen())
            .setWhen(information.getWhen())
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 5, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .setDeleteIntent(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, deleteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .build();
```

Note, most of the usecase happend when the app is in foreground

Comment: Use notification channel ids for grouping.

Comment: There's already a channel. How can i catch the event of the user clicking on the entire group of notification ?